# How can I find the time complexity for inner loops that depend on "i" from the outer loop:

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o

how can I find the time complexity of inner loops that depend on `i` from an outer loop such as:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
    for(int j = n - 1; j >= n - 1 - i; j--) {
        sum = i + j;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

I'm having such a hard time figuring out the time complexity for that. I know that if there is `i` we use the summation rule but in this case how is that going to be?

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop performs 1 iteration at the start, increasing up to `n*n` iterations by the end.

```
i       iterations of inner loop
-       ------------------------
0       1
1       2
2       3
...
n*n-2   n*n-1
n*n-1   n*n
```

The total number of iterations of the inner loop is the sum of these:

[image]

or

[image]

The time complexity is therefore *Θ*(*n<sup>4</sup>*).

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop changes with the outer loop, so it is dependent. You cannot directly find the cost of only the inner loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {              \\ \sum_{i=0}^{n^2}
    for(int j = n - 1; j >= n - 1 - i; j--) { \\  \sum_{n-1-i}^{n-1} 
        sum = i + j;                          \\      1
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

So, we have to solve

[image: Gaussian Sums made in LaTeX]

**Note:** there was a typo on the Latex image, and it is updated. Thanks to [Anatolii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055395/anatolii)